# Categorical Representation of the Set of All Strings

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

Let $A$ be a small preordered category. How would we define a preordered category $\mathcal A$ for all strings over $A$ (e.g., Kleene Closure) ordered by the [subword order](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~jean/kruskal.pdf) (Def'n $3.1$) $\leqslant$?

My first attempt was to do something with Kleisli or Ellenberg-Moore categories but I didn't see it working.

Comment: Your question is not so clear... at least not to me. It seems that you are looking for a construction of some sort that given a preordered category $A$ it gives you back a preordered category $\mathcal A$.... but it is not clear what property this category should satisfy: what should be the class of objects? what should be the class of arrows? Try adding more details please.

Comment: @GiorgioMossa The class of objects are the elements of $A$ and the arrows are morphisms where given $u,v\in A$, then $u\to v$ iff $u\leqslant v$. My apologies, I should have been more detailed.

Comment: So, are you saying that $\mathcal A$ is nothing but the category/preorder of $\text{Ob}(A)$?

Comment: @GiorgioMossa Esssentially...

Comment: Then does this answer to your question?

Comment: @GiorgioMossa what does?

Comment: $\mathcal A$ is the preorder of $A$

Comment: @GiorgioMossa Umm... I don't think so. I was thinking about this: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Preorder_Category

Comment: So is it  your question about **preorder** category, not **preordered** category?

Comment: @GiorgioMossa Ya. My apologies for the wrong wording

Comment: Then I believe what are you looking for should be the free-strict-monoidal category over your category. I should make some check, but I'm pretty sure. Maybe later I'll be able to write a full answer, so stay tuned. :)

Comment: @GiorgioMossa I will be awaiting your full answer. Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39820/discussion-between-julian-rachman-and-giorgio-mossa).